# How to avoid multiple login for the same user

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005

I wanted to stop multiple login of the same user. So, I created a table which keeps track of users who have logged in. When they log in, the data will be entered in the table. When they click on logout, data and session will be removed.

The problem is, when they close the browser window without logging out, they won't be able to login ever again.

Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Are you using `Microsoft SQL Server` or `MySQL`? I've removed the `MySQL` tag temporary because I guess you're using `SQL Server`. Feel free to add the correct tags to your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to delete inforamtion in table on global event `Session_End` in `global.asax.cs` file

```
protected void Session_End(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //delete from database where userID = Session["userID"]
}
```

Comment: Ty . I tried doing that . It will work only when user clicks on logout.

Comment: @HaraHara, the above mentioned solution is right, and it will fire when the automatic timeout happens on the server. i.e., if you've set the timeout period to 10 minutes. The Session_End would fire after 10 minutes of the last activity performed by a SessionID

Comment: which session mode should i use? I am using SQL server for DB. Do i have to use sql server mode or InProc mode?

Comment: @HaraHara, you can choose any session mode. It doesn't matter.

Comment: @HaraHara: If you are using SqlServer mode for session Session_End will ignored if user not cliecked on logout. Check my answer.

Comment: @x2: This also creates a gap between the closing of the browser and the timeout of the session.

Answer (score 2):

If we are speaking about 'StateServer or SQLServer' session mode than:

`Session_End` event will fire once you call `Session.Abandon()`. There is job `ASPState_Job_DeleteExpiredSessions` on sql server, that expire user sessions if user not logged out using logout button. This job call `DeleteExpiredSessions` stored procedure, so i suppose you should place some logic(remove logged user) into this stored procedure.

from [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178583.aspx):

> You can handle the Session_OnEnd event
>   by adding a subroutine named
>   Session_OnEnd to the Global.asax file.
>   The Session_OnEnd subroutine is run
>   when the Abandon method has been
>   called or when the session has
>   expired. A session expires when the
>   number of minutes specified by the
>   Timeout property passes without a
>   request being made for the session.
>
> **The Session_OnEnd event is supported
>   only when the session state Mode
>   property is set to InProc, which is
>   the default. If the session state Mode
>   is StateServer or SQLServer, then the
>   Session_OnEnd event in the Global.asax
>   file is ignored**. If the session state
>   Mode is set to Custom, then support
>   for the Session_OnEnd event is
>   determined by the custom session-state
>   store provider.
>
> You can use the Session_OnEnd event to
>   clean up session-related information
>   such as information for a user that is
>   tracked in a data source by the
>   SessionID value.

Answer (score 1):

Keap you session time out short and when session is diposed log user out automaticly

Comment: That won't delete data from database.

Comment: you can set your own cutom code when it happend and remote it from there user entriy in database

Answer (score 0):

Just keep one session variable saying `true`/`false` depending on login status. True - user is already logged in, False - not logged in.

In many cases I have a User object saved into the session, so I just check it against `null`, which just returns the authenticated user or null (anonymous).

Simple enough and without DB involved.

**EDIT**:

If comments below understand the problem correctly then please despite this answer. I was referring to the situation when you don't want an authenticated user to log in again during the same session.

Comment: I don't think you understood the question correctly. He doesn't want to check IF a user is logged in, he wants to make sure that a user is logged in only ONCE.

Comment: One session variable won't inform different instances of clients whether they have logged in or not